# Upgrading to gcc 4.9 with Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Tags: apt, upgrade, 10.04, gcc

I want to install gcc/g++ 4.9 and I started by updating all paths inside sources.list from "us.archive" to "old-releases". I Then dobbelt checked that gcc-4.9 is inside the website repository.

Then with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9
```

I get the error:

```
Couldn't find package gcc-4.9
```

Can anybody explain why?

Comment: I don't think 4.9 is the full version name

Comment: @ravery There exists a package called gcc-4.9

Comment: @Arun --  thank you, I see now. I thought he was specifying version of gcc

Comment: Because the PPA doesn't support obsolete releases, which you know you are using?

Comment: @muru I found that it was possible to upgrade to gcc-4.8 hence I thought it could work for 4.9 too, but your saying that gcc-4.9 isn't supported by 10.04 LTS ?

Comment: @Ivan I'm saying don't expect anything for an obsolete release. Things may work, may not work, may work halfway.

Comment: If you [filter the PPA content list on release name "Lucid"](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test?field.series_filter=lucid) you will see that it only offers GCC 4.5, 4.6, 4.7,.4.8, and 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking it up with [aptitude](https://wiki.debian.org/Aptitude): `aptitude search gcc-4.9`

This version may very well not exist since release 10.04 is obsolete.